# Performance monitoring tool for mobile safari web application

Tags: ios, performance, mobile, web-applications, safari

I am working on a web application. I can test my performance of web app including memory and cpu usage in desktop using chrome Dev tools. I want similar application so that I can measure my web app performance running on iPad and iPhone in safari.
Is such type of tool available?

PS: After some research, People advising for xcode instruments. but I am not able to recognize how I can test using instruments.

Please help.